# Silverlight Visifire Chart Axis Minimum Interval

Tags: silverlight, charts, intervals, visifire

I have a stacked bar chart with Days values displayed on the X Axis that needs to dynamically change it's size.

When I have a small number of points, let's say 2, the Interval value has a small value and instead of seeing only 2 labels on the axis, there are a lot many.

The ideal value would be Interval = 1 (with IntervalType="Days"). But this causes another problem: when the Interval is set like this, in case there are a lot of points and the size of the chart is small, the labels are all displayed because the Interval does not change.

Here are a few screenshots to illustrate the problem:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYQ1e.png

Interval left default and enough points (5/31 - 6/10):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYQ1e.png#0

Interval left default and small number of points (5/31 - 6/1):
...#1

Interval = 1 and small number of points (5/31 - 6/1):
...#2

Interval = 1 and large number of points (5/31 - 7/29):
...#3

My question is: Is there a way to have both?  To set the Interval to 1 but still get rid of excess labels when the don't fit?
My idea was to have Interval be a maximum of 1 and the default calculated value, and I tried to implement it by changing it at the Rendered event, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. I just went with a Numeric DataMapping instead of the DateTime one and mapped the AxisXLabel and ToolTipText to the date. 
With dates it seems a little buggy but this way it works fine.